# Nested foreach that depends on variable of the previous foreach

Tags: c#, list, while-loop, foreach, iteration

I've wrote a piece of code that correctly loops trough lists and does what I need, but I think it's a bit stupid how I did it, and I'm looking for a way too write this effectively, with a while, or repeat loop.

Here's what is working:

```
            data = List<string>; //a new list of strings
            foreach (var string in data) 
            {
                data = createNewList(string); //for every string inside the previous, a new list is created
                foreach (var string2 in data) 
                {
                     data = createNewList(string2); //for every string in the last one, a new list is created
                    foreach (var string3 in data)
                    {
                         data = createNewList(string3);
                        foreach (var string4 in data)
                        {
                                //And so on...
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

What I tried (with the real code) stops without bugs after the first iteration... but I'd like it to make infinite, as long as there's a sub list being made

```
            dataSingles = addFolderItemsList(sourcelist);
            foreach (NodeN node in dataSingles)
            {
               

                while (flag > 0)
                {
                    flag = 0;
                    foreach (NodeN subnode in dataSingles)
                    {
                        dataSingles = addFolderItemsList(subnode.ChildrenN);
                        if (dataSingles.Count() > 0) { flag = 1; }
                      
                    }
                   
                   
            }
```

Comment: Seems like you're looking for recursion. Beware, though: recursive code might throw a `StackOverflowException` if the recursive is too deep.

Comment: Indeed, it's recursion I want to do. Do I get some kind of medal in this forum if I achieve that error by accident?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the recursive ProcessList function to iterate through your lists.

```
void ProcessList(List<string> data)
{
    List<string> newData = new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        newData.AddRange(createNewList(item));
    }

    if (newData.Count > 0)
    {
        ProcessList(newData);
    }
}

ProcessList(data);
```

If you wanted to use a while loop use my snippet below, recursion would be the best way to go for this solution though so just keep that in mind

```
List<string> currentData = data; 
while(currentData.Count > 0) 
{
    List<string> newData = new List<string>();
    foreach(var item in currentData) 
    {
        newData.AddRange(createNewList(item));
    }
    currentData = newData;
}
```